# What to use :who or whom in this context

Tags: who-whom

> He is the first person who/whom I know has ever been to Africa.

which relative pronoun works in this context and why?

Comment: I answered your question as written, though I do wonder whether you actually mean "who I know has ever been to Africa". It would seem more likely that you would want to say "I know who has ever been to Africa".

Comment: @SamBC Thank you for the answer and pointing out the ambiguity of my sentence, it is really helpful !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you aren't producing work to be read by an exceptionally stuffy grammarian who adheres to 19th century prescriptivist grammar, there's a simple rule to follow here.

**If in doubt, use *who*.**

This is simply because it is not necessary to use *whom* in English as it is generally spoken by native speakers. The only time it would seem strange to use *who* rather than *whom* is when you've rearranged a sentence to fit the usually-ignored rule against ending a sentence with a preposition:

> She is the woman **with whom** I used to live.

The most natural way to say that for most people is:

> She is the woman I used to live **with**.

But if you rearrange to move the preposition earlier, and use *who*, it sounds wrong:

> She is the woman **with who** I used to live.

Other than that, just use who - unless you have a stuffy grammarian reading your work.